# How to check if there exist any GET input in php

Tags: php

I have an php script which takes multipal input using different variables and not all are used always so i was wondering is there a way to if there is no GET input at all so that i can display my homepage,one way i am currently using is checking each variable with `isset()` but i was wondering if there exist any simpler code to do this..
i tried this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET))
echo "exist";
else
echo "do not exist";
?>
```

but it prints "exist" even when no GET input is supplied